# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium-android

I'm beginner in this, so be patient :) 
I try to launch simple test and have a problem caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpCommandCodec

I have set java-client 7.1.0 and selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59
Other libs u can see here: https://screencast.com/t/I3Zg7KDFxbO Seems like I have done something wrong in dependencies but I couldn't find understandable (for me) answer what I should do.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:86)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:96)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
at FirstTest.setUp(FirstTest.kt:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpCommandCodec
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 36 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a webdriver e.g.:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec is part of

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which is a dependency from selenium-firefox-driver

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't help.

Comment: Do you use maven?

Comment: no, I don't use any builder for now. Just adding libs to external in IDEA. I've added the remote driver, but the error is still the same https://screencast.com/t/6S7c4ZNPq4

Comment: ok so you have to add every dependency by hand, like selenium-remote-driver

Comment: Well as I can see W3CHttpCommandCodec in the package org.openqa.selenium.remote.http, but it needs to be in org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c ...

Comment: Solved by updating to the latest selenium-remote-driver (4.*). Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

Was facing the same issue, I just updated the selenium java client to 4.0.0-alpha-1 issue got resolved

my dependecies :

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-alpha-1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may get this exception when you update one dependency. For example: Appium java client to latest but the dependent Selenium Java dependencies are not updated to latest then you might expect this issue. So look at your Maven dependencies of related ones.