# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec

Is this error because of dependencies? I inspected similar problems at Stack Overflow, but didn't came up with an idea how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

public class base {
    
    public static AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {
        
        File appdir=new File("src");
        File app=new File(appdir,"ApiDemos-debug.apk");
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Emulator1");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"uiautomator2");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver=new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        return driver;
    }
```

This is what I see after running the test:

```
    авг 13, 2019 11:26:55 PM io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1 lambda$0
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:41)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.startSession(AppiumDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:86)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:96)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at base.Capabilities(base.java:22)
    at basics.main(basics.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpCommandCodec
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: There is similar answer already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933457/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-remote-codec-w3c-w3chttpcomm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933457/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-remote-codec-w3c-w3chttpcomm)

Comment: I saw this solution in some answers and that it can be set in maven but I dont know how 

<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: @Mykhailo Moskura - you are right, but unfortunately I have no idea about how to use maven or play with dependencies (

Comment: You need to add dependency inside dependencies tag in pom.xml which is in root path of your project

Answer (score 1):

You're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) due to:

1. [Appium Java Client 7.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0) has [Selenium Java 3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.141.59) as a part of its [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies)
2. You explicitly declare [Selenium Java Client 3.12.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java/3.12.0) as your project dependency
3. [Java Classloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader) picks up the wrong classes with not matching APIs and dependencies - that's why you're getting this error

The solution is to **remove Selenium Java Client 3.12.0 from your project dependencies/classpath**, Maven will resolve the required dependencies on its own.

See [Appium - Code Examples - Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) article for more information and sample projects.

Comment: It worked after adding commons-lang3-3.7 jar and changing java-client 7.1.0 jar to 7.0.0 in external libraries. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @VadimAbramenko Hello. I have the same issue as you but still can't figure the solution. Could you please help me?